# where used list - Querying the Snowflake metadata information

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to query the metadata DDL to get the list of views using a table? 
or list of views using another view etc?

i.e. where used list of a table or view across various schemas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there isn't. However, Snowflake offers GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES() that returns a list of objects that a specified view references. You can materialize the results of this function for all views and then do a reverse lookup for referring entities for a particular table/view.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/get_object_references.html

Answer (score 3):

As Sahaj indicated in his answer, there is no direct way to select the names of all views using a table. You can create a [stored procedure](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html) to fetch this information using [`GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/get_object_references.html), however, with the caveat that it will be quite slow if you have a significant number of objects in your database:

```
-- Finds all references to the table with the provided name in the
-- active database. Returns them as a comma-separated list.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetTableReferences(DATABASE_NAME VARCHAR, SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR, TABLE_NAME VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT AS $$
var query = "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = '" + DATABASE_NAME + "'";
var statement = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: query} );
var result_set = statement.execute();
var matches = '';
while (result_set.next())  {
  var schema = result_set.getColumnValue(1);
  var table = result_set.getColumnValue(2);
  var object_references_query =
    "SELECT 1 FROM TABLE(GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES(DATABASE_NAME => '" + DATABASE_NAME
    + "', SCHEMA_NAME => '" + schema + "', OBJECT_NAME => '" + table + "')) WHERE REFERENCED_SCHEMA_NAME = '"
    + SCHEMA_NAME + "' AND REFERENCED_OBJECT_NAME = '" + TABLE_NAME + "'";
  var object_references_statement = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: object_references_query} );
  try {
    if (object_references_statement.execute().next()) {
      // This is a match
      if (matches.length !== 0) {
        matches += ",";
      }
      matches += schema + "." + table;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // Ignore invalid views.
  }
}
return matches;
$$;

CALL GetTableReferences('MY_DATABASE_NAME', 'MY_SCHEMA_NAME', 'MY_TABLE_NAME');
```

Comment: Thank You Elliott. GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES function has the limitation to provide the list for materialized views and we are unable to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could search the view definitions for the table- example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
where VIEW_DEFINITION LIKE '%*your_table_name*%'
```